# Highmaps map is not loading? Why isnt loading?

Tags: highmaps

Highmaps was loading yesterday.But now its not loading.I checked the console but there is no error.
Why its not loading?

pics:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you've included the necessary JS libraries and are referring to the map with the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

-check to make sure that you're pulling data into your map
-check all of your included libraries are in order e.g.

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
```